# Save log on database vs save logo on a local file

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-performance

Hy All
I have a question about saving some logs. I so that there are 2 ways usually used: Save each log in a database table or save logs on a local file.
My question is: which is less resource consuming and faster?

Thanks!

Comment: http://hungred.com/useful-information/best-way-log-details-database-or-file-log/

Comment: Thanks caramba for the link

Comment: I saw a project with a serious application error.  It failed to log the error because of the logging mechanism hit the _same_ database error that it was trying to log.  It took days to even know that there was an error.  We trusted the log, but it said nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both of ways are using now in applications. 
but saving logs in database is more secure than saving on disk as file.
if you want to log errors of your code, so you need to log file too. because sometimes you want to save logs in database and database has problem(i mean errors like too has many connections and ...) 
Also,reading and writing in files are slower than database.
 
So saving logs in database is better than saving logs on file but you can have logs for database error as file.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hey Really Nice. What I so in apps is that those tables are huge and because of that the database is really big (of course in time). Bun for files i believe that you can check the size of the file and if the size it to big then create a new file.

Comment: you can save your records in database and add trigger or cron job to delete some records after sometimes. It means you can add timestamp field to your log table. This way can save your latest records.

Answer (score 3):

It's depends on what do you want from logs
If you are working on Linux. So log to file is better than anything else.

If you plan to manage your log to find out bugs or anything else, databases is good.

Keep in mind, using database to logs have some prof and cons, and all of them are not good enough for this purpose, exactly RDBMS databases. I suggest you consider using NoSQL databases like [redis](http://sunilarora.org/another-redis-use-case-centralized-logging/), mongodb and ...

Also before starting to save logs to database you should know for what kind of output and how long , do you want to save logs to database

Comment: Thank you irmorteza for sharing those great informations.